# Excuting cpp file from Python

Tags: python, c++

I need to execute C++ code to acquire images to process in python.

I need to use these commands from python:

1. make and
2. ./name_of_the_executable

Could anybody please help know me how to do it?

Comment: Your question implies these are full executable programs (is that the `make` utility you wish to run?), in which case they need to be run in another process, see subprocess module in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.  How are the images to be passed into python?  If you get problems, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am going to periodically read the image file from python code and process it using OpenCV. To have the images in the particular path, I need to run a C++ executable. Can I use something like this?

Comment: Is the C++ a full executable program, or a DLL/.so?  You say 'image file', does the C++ create a file then?   Did you look at the subprocess module?

Answer (score 2):

Look For python.net which is cable of making a call to the interfaces written in .net supported languages.
What all you need to do is

**Steps:**

1. Download and put it two files `Python.Runtime.dll` and `clr.pyd` in your DLLs folder.
2. From you `>>>`(triple greater than prompt )Python prompt Try

   `>>>import clr`
3. if it doesn't gives any error you are good to go .
4. Next You need to do is put Your C++ Dll inside Lib/site-packages Folder .

(This is not mandatory but good for beginners).

5. Next to `import clr` try importing your Dll as a module `import YourDllName`

If step 5 doesn't gives you a error . Hola You are done That's All Folks :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard module `os` provides the `system` call that allows execution of arbitrary operating system commands from Python. For example:

```
import os
os.system('ls -latr');
```